# In springboot, how to rename Form-data fields while mapping using @ModelAttribute?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am working with spring-boot, in my controller, I am receiving a formData. I'm mapping the request to the POJO using the @ModelAttribute however, the formData names are not uniform. In this case, @JsonProperty is not helping.
I was looking for some annotation or way so I can rename these fields while mapping.

Curl sample-

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/demo' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
--form 'deviceID="123"' \
--form 'ASN="123"' \
--form 'portal="demoportal"' \
--form 'str_ScanData=@"/D:/sample.xml"'
```

My Controller sample-

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/demo", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}) public ResponseEntity<demoDto> demoController(
@ModelAttribute DemoRequest demoRequest)
```

My POJO for Request -

```
Class DemoRequest {
// what i have right now
   private String deviceID;
    private String ASN;
    private String portal;
    private MultipartFile str_ScanData;
// getter setters constructor

// What I want to have
   private String deviceId; //camelcase
    private String asn; //rename
    private String portal;
    private MultipartFile uploadedFile; //rename
}
```

I am new to using forums and spring-boot. Please let me know if I am on wrong track or have not posted any relevant info.

Comment: As an `@ModelAttribute` is exclusively used for binding a Web form into the controller, I have simply replicated the form attributes exactly, even if the property names aren't Java-standard, to accurately reflect the form contents. I believe that altering the names would require a custom binder.

Comment: You keep your dto by matching the form fields and use @Column or JsonProperty on Entity class.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  I would have left it to be same named as form data but my Sonar keep ringing :D. So , I thought there must be some way.

Comment: I would say this is a specific case where suppressing the Sonar warnings is justified.

Comment: @Alien I wanted to basically rename the fields in my dto as the form fields are not consistent.

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty old question, but I just came across the same problem and figured out that Spring (at least in `spring-webflux`, but it should work the same for `spring-web`) makes use of `@ConstructorProperties` annotation in `ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver`.

That means the following is possible for a custom field naming inside a `ModelAttribute`:

```
public class DemoRequest {

    private final String deviceId;
    private final String asn; 
    private final String portal;
    private final MultipartFile uploadedFile;
    
    @ConstructorProperties({"deviceID", "ASN", "portal", "str_ScanData"})
    public DemoRequest(String deviceId, String asn, String portal, MultipartFile uploadedFile) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.asn = asn;
        this.portal = portal;
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }
}
```